# How to add LaTeX in LinkedIn article

Tags: equations, online

I am writing an article on LinkedIn and in my article there are some mathematical equations I need to include.

I am wondering if it is possible to add LaTeX mathematical symbols in the LinkedIn article. Or, if not, if there is another way to do it.

Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: From a quick look at the LinkedIn editor and the help pages it does not appear to be possible to add LaTeX equations (or any kind of equations for that matter). If it is just about symbols then you can enter unicode characters in your article, but for real equations you probably need to write the equation in LaTeX elsewhere and make a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not possible to put LaTeX directly in the text of a LinkedIn post. There are some symbols that you can add to somewhat approximate an equation but that does not work in most cases. Your other option is to add a screenshot of the equations as a photo. That's not a great choice either. What I would probably do, is write a text summary and add a link to a personal website that contains the full post including any equations.